# How to add the filter in Odata?

Tags: c#, odata

I just filter all record but I can`t filter one record.
[image]

```cs
[HttpGet("GetContact")]
       
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ContactEm>>> GetContactEms([FromQuery(Name = "top")] int top, [FromQuery(Name = "$skip")] int skip, [FromQuery(Name = "$orderby")] string orderny, [FromQuery(Name = "$filter")] string filter)
{
    return await _context.ContactEms.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "switching on" filtering feature, supported by OData ($filter=...)
you should create a controller, inherited from `ODataController`, with [EnableQuery] attribute on the method. Consider using [official manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) for a detailed walkthrough.
In your case, it should be something like:

```
public class ContactEmsController : ODataController
{
...
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ContactEm> Get()
    {
        return _context.ContactEms;
    }
}
```